# Dynamically made page doesn't receive jQuery Mobile "enhanced" CSS classes when inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, iframe

I am writing a script that transforms an older existing site into a "mobile optimized" one. I'm doing this by picking out the pieces that I want from the existing HTML and creating jQuery Mobile markup from scratch using jQuery, for example (coffee):

```
page = $('<div data-role="page"></div>')
header = $('<div data-role="header"></div>').append(...)
body = $('<div data-role="main" class="ui-content"></div>').append(...)

page.append header
page.append content
```

I'm then replacing the iframe body with the page, followed by injecting JQM (@context here is the iframe):

```
$('head', @context).append $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css">')
$('head', @context).append $('<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">')
$('head', @context).append $('<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js">')
```

(I've also tried injecting JQM before appending to the body)

Most answers on SO suggest using `trigger('create')` to "refresh" the enhancements, but that doesn't seem to work. I'm doing it on the page, is that correct?

```
$('[data-role="page"]').trigger 'create'
```

Also, this works when I do it outside of the iframe (replacing the entire document's body instead of 1 frame) - only fails inside of an iframe. Unfortunately I've found that I need to be working within the iframe. What am I doing wrong?

When inspecting the HTML, I noticed that the tags do not receive the enhanced classes (I think stuff like "ui-mobile"?) - they do when I'm not using an iframe. My only problem is that the jQM styles do not apply, the elements themselves are there but they look like the default controls.

Comment: with JQM 1.4 you need to call `enhanceWithin()` on the parent that contains your element, so most likely `$(document).enhanceWithin()`

Comment: Still nothing, I tried it on both the main document and the iframe document.

Comment: it should work if triggered from **inside** the iFrame. Do you have access to the iFrame `document`?

Comment: Yes I do. To trigger it I tried `$(frames[1].document).enhanceWithin()` - is that not what you mean?

Comment: That will not work. Log `frames[1].document`. In general you cannot "touch" the DOM contained inside an iFrame from the page containing it. It would be possible on same domain iFrames, but you should enhanced the iFrame content from inside the iFrame, so if you are on `bar.html` with an iFrame pointing to `foo.html`, you need to enhance the page from inside `foo.html`. You cannot do this from `bar.html`

Comment: also try logging `frames[1].contentWindow`

Comment: I am injecting all of the elements into the frames body using `frames[1].document` - what do you mean I cannot touch it? Can I not enhance the page if I'm injecting my script into the main document's `<head>`? I am pretty much tied to injecting the script into the main document and then editing the frame from there.

Comment: easy way to find out: can you log what is inside your iframe? So if you "inject" a header into the iframe, can you access it from the console?